# Deleting User profile service and recreating it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell

If I delete the User Profile Service Application from the central administration, will that create an issue for user using SharePoint. I am trying to delete that and recreate again since the User profile synchronization is not starting. But i am concern what happens if I delete user profile services can users use sharepoint during that time or they will not have access to the sharepoint site.

Thanks
Mohammed

Answer (score 1):

User Profile Service doesn't provide permissioning to Site Collections. If you delete the UPA, users will maintain the access they have.

Comment: so there is no downtime or anything required I can just delete it and recreate it again without any issues?

Comment: Certain features that rely on UPA (e.g. People Search) will not function. I'd always recommend this maintenance occur after hours.

Comment: Alright, thanks you. I will give a try and update it.

Answer (score 0):

As Trevor Mentioned, their will be no permission issue, But keep in mind, once you delete the User profile service then User will lose their profile's data. Also if you are using the target audience that will also not work.

recently we have seen an issue with Workflow where someone making a call to User profile service then workflow throws the error.